# Rails text field with jpg url

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails project for news board.

When the external link about image like :https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pDBv.jpg which I type in the text_field and submit, I get the view:

> bla bla bla bla bla.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pDBv.jpg

html is as follow:

```
<p><%= @news.contents %></p>
```

I want to let it display image not just string and I try to add `<img src="">` tag in the text_field.

But I get view:

> bla bla bla bla bla.... `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pDBv.jpg">`

How can I make the image to display like this:

> bla bla bla bla bla.... [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to render the string as HTML, and you are almost there.

To achieve this, one thing you can do is to specify it as a `html_safe` content. Something like the following:

```
<%= (@news.contents).html_safe %>
```

This should solve it for you.

PS: this is assuming that `@news.contents` contains everything needed to render html, i.e, the image tag is present there. For example:

```
@news.contents = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/bn4B6Ko.jpg">'
<%= (@news.contents).html_safe %>
```

Hope this helps.